# Package animate with android

Tags: pdf, animate, android

Could you please suggest to me a way to visualize on Android systems a PDF which contains animations realized with the animate package? I already tried with the Adobe Reader for Android, but it didn't work.
Thank you in advance!
Maurizio

Comment: Did you use the fullscreen/presentation mode?

Answer (score 1):

`animate`-made animations rely on JavaScript. None of the known PDF readers on mobile platforms include a JavaScript engine. Therefore it is currently impossible to play this kind of animations on mobile devices.

Though I doubt it will help a lot, you could vote for a adding JavaScript on the Feature Request page of Acrobat Reader for Android:

https://acrobat.uservoice.com/forums/595576-acrobat-reader-for-android?query=javascript